# Minimum value of the inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

Give $a_{1}\geq a_{2}\geq ...\geq a_{n}> 0$ and a positive integer m . Find the minimum value of the following the inequality:

$\left ( a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{a_{1}^{m}}+ \frac{1}{a_{2}^{m}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n}^{m}}\right )$

Please help me to solve the above problem. I try but not success.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $m$ positive?

Comment: yeah. m is positive

Comment: "find the minimum value of the folowing inequality" But youve stated a product.. did you mean $(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)\geq(\frac{1}{a_1^m}+\frac{1}{a_2^m}+...+\frac{1}{a_n^m})$??

Comment: If $m>1$ just take all $a_i =a \to \infty$ to show there is no minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define
$$
F_m(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^{-m}\right).
$$

- If $m>1$ we have
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}F_m(x,\ldots,x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(n^2x^{1-m})=0$$
  So, $\inf F_m=0$, in this case. (Note that the minimum in not attained here).
- If $m=1$, then by th Cauchy schwarz inequality we have
  $$n^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cdot \frac{1}{a_k}\right)^2\leq
  \left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^{-1}\right)=F_1(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
  $$
  with equality if $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n$. So, $\min F_1=n^2~$ in this case.